# Items not deleting from LIST

Tags: vb.net

I have a list that I am using to hold a queue of commands.

I need to loop though each item of the queue, executing the commands, deleting them as it goes along.

The items weren't being deleted from the queue.

Here is a quick test code which doesn't work either:

```
Dim MyList As New List(Of String)

For i = 0 To 5
   MyList.Add(i)
Next
MsgBox(MyList.Count) 'returns 6

MyList.Remove(2)
MyList.Remove(4)

For i = 0 To MyList.Count - 1
   MsgBox(MyList(i)) 'pops up 6 times, including the 2 "deleted" ones.
Next
MsgBox(MyList.Count) 'still returns 6
```

The items don't get deleted.

Comment: As an alternative there is the Queue Type; `Queue<T>.Dequeue`

Comment: Your quick test code doesn't do what you describe.  Only 4 messages "pop up" and the last message box pops up 4.

Comment: Also, after looking at your question history, please read this post from the meta site regarding the use of tags in your titles: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: @valverij Sorry! I'll leave them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MyList.Remove` calls, do you mean to remove the value `2` or remove at the index of `2`? If you meant to remove at the index, then use `RemoveAt`:

```
MyList.RemoveAt(2)
```

Otherwise, if your code is actually exactly as you've posted, then it should be working fine. I plugged this into a little console app, and it worked:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim MyList As New List(Of String)

    For i = 0 To 5
        MyList.Add(i)
        Console.WriteLine("i: {0}", i)
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("MyList.Count: {0}", MyList.Count)

    MyList.Remove(2)
    MyList.Remove(4)

    For i = 0 To MyList.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("MyList({0}): {1}", i, MyList(i))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("MyList.Count: {0}", MyList.Count)
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Output:

```
i: 0
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
i: 5
MyList.Count: 6
MyList(0): 0
MyList(1): 1
MyList(2): 3
MyList(3): 5
MyList.Count: 4
```

Comment: I need to remove the index. So the 2nd item etc. Thanks. I will look at this.